# AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID URL

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In this call:

```
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)urlSound, &audioID);
```

does urlSound have to be a local file? I am passing in a wav file on a website but it's returning 0. Is that why?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

(The URL is converted using CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation and then opened with the standard UNIX open(2) function, so it's pretty sure that URL should point to a local file.)